# VHDL: is there a way to create an entity into which constants can be passed?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, hdl

Lets say we want to create a generic t flip flop counter, the structure of this kind of counter is perfectly repetitive, and you can synthesize one with arbitrary length just using a `for generate`

however the bound for that `for` and the length of the output is internal to the file, a constant, is there a way to sort of passing an argument when creating a component so as to define the length of the counter when creating the component instead of in the file?

here is the code of the counter i made

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity counterTst is
port(
    enable: in      STD_LOGIC;
    clk:        in      STD_LOGIC;
    rst:        in      STD_LOGIC;
    output: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0)
    );
end counterTst;


architecture rtl of counterTst is

constant COUNTER_LEN:   integer := 4;

component t_ff  is
port(
    rst:    in      STD_LOGIC;
    clk:    in      STD_LOGIC;
    inp:    in      STD_LOGIC;
    t:      out STD_LOGIC
    );
end component t_ff;

signal  tin:    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(COUNTER_LEN-2 downto 0);
signal  tout:   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(COUNTER_LEN-1 downto 0);

begin

T_CHAIN_GEN:    for i in 0 to COUNTER_LEN-1 generate
    START_POS: if i = 0 generate
        FF0:    t_ff    port    map(rst, clk, enable, tout(0));
    end generate START_POS;

    POS_1:  if i = 1 generate
        tin(0) <= tout(0) and enable;
        FF1:    t_ff    port    map(rst, clk, tin(0), tout(1));
    end generate POS_2;

    POS_N:  if i > 1 generate
        tin(i-1) <= tout(i-1) and tin(i-2);
        FFX:    t_ff    port    map(rst, clk, tin(i-1), tout(i));
    end generate POS_N;
end generate T_CHAIN_GEN;

output <= tout;

end rtl;
```

Comment: Either add a generic above your ports or put the constant into a package.

Comment: [Relevant (old) Code Review answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/73794/52915)

Comment: Generic with default values. Then in the component instantiation part(in other modules), initialise it with the desired value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is called a 'generic':

I could show an example here, but there are plenty of example on the WWW once you know what to look for: https://www.nandland.com/vhdl/examples/example-generic.html

Answer (score 9):

Add a generic clause to your entity. It allows you to pass in e.g. constants:

```
entity counterTst is
  generic (
    constant COUNTER_LEN : integer -- := 4
  );
  port (
    enable: in  STD_LOGIC;
    clk:    in  STD_LOGIC;
    rst:    in  STD_LOGIC;
    output: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(COUNTER_LEN - 1 downto 0)
  );
end counterTst;


architecture rtl of counterTst is

  -- constant COUNTER_LEN:   integer := 4;
```

Moreover generic values can be used in you port clause to size ports. A generic can have a default value, thus the user doesn't need to apply it in a generic map. In you case, you shouldn't apply a default value to force the user to think about his choice :).

And here is the usage:

```
cnt : entity work.counterTst
  generic map (
    COUNTER_LEN => 4
  )
  port map (
    -- ...
  );
```

Like in a port map, you map generics in a *generic map*.

Answer (score 5):

Since VHDL 2008, you can also make `output` an unconstrained port and then infer the counter length from that port, as given during instantiation:

```
entity counterTst is
    port(
        enable: in  std_logic;
        clk:    in  std_logic;
        rst:    in  std_logic;
        output: out std_logic_vector
    );
end entity;

architecture rtl of counterTst is
    constant counter_len: natural := output'length;

    -- ...
end architecture;
```

Just one thing to be careful about: The instantiation will define the full range of `output`, so it might be an `std_logic_vector(counter_len downto 1)` or even a dreaded `to` range. Since you assign `output` from a local signal, this is not an issue, but it could be problematic if you try to index `output` directly.

Comment: Quite nifty. Another thing to be careful about (almost a meme at this point) is that VHDL 2008 support can still(!) be rather flaky, with different synthesis/simulation tools supporting a different subset of the standard, if any at all.

Comment: It's e.g. supported by Vivado 2018.3.